# How to get customer gender value with text in magento2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, customer-attribute

I want get **customer gender** value like **Male** or **Female** in magento2?

and also want to get gender attribute value like 1,2,3

text: Male, Female and Not Specified

Answer (score 1):

You can get gender value and text:

```
<?php

$customerId = 12;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerId);

//Get gender value like 1,2,3
$genderValue = $customer->getCustomAttributeText('gender')->getValue();

//Get gender text like male, female
$genderText = $customer->getResource()
->getAttribute('gender')
    ->getSource()
        ->getOptionText($customer->getData('gender'));

echo $genderText;
```