# How to get customer gender as text from its integer value in magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks

I want to get customer gender value like Male or Female in magento2?
How to get it in `\Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info` block,

I am doing something like this

```
$block->getCustomer()->getGender()
```

I referred this link
 [How to get customer gender value with text in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225246/how-to-get-customer-gender-value-with-text-in-magento2)

I don't want to use `ObjectManager` just for gender, there must be something via this method `$block->getCustomer()->getGender()`

Comment: what's wrong with `$block->getCustomer()->getGender()`? you don't have to use the objectmanager to get the customer. use the customersession

Comment: `$block->getCustomer()->getGender() ` gives me integer value

Comment: but the answer describes how to get the text-value. I don't get your problem. just don't use the objectmanager to get the customer. that's bad practice

Comment: this $block->getCustomer()->getGender() gives me integrer value, Obviously i dont want to show integer on UI to user,i want text, like male or female

Comment: look at the lower part of the code in your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this below code in your block :

```
protected $customerSession;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    ....
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    //$customerId = 12;
    if($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
        $customer = $this->customerSession->getCustomer();
        $customerId = $customer->getId();
        $genderText = $customer->getAttribute('gender')->getSource()->getOptionText($customer->getData('gender'));
        echo $genderText;
    } else{
        echo 'customer is not logged in';
    }
}
```

Comment: use the session to get the customer

Comment: Updated answer :)

Comment: no.... why not use the customer? why are oyu loading it again? that's the whole point of using the session. throw away the factory. you don't need it.

Comment: @PhilippSander Yes Exactly, remove customer Factory

Comment: @RohanHapani also, no need to use getResource() as it is deprecated, you can use getAttribute() directly on $customer

Comment: Just a minute. I updated my answer in few minutes.

Comment: check my updated answer. You can now accept and upvote it. So, it's useful for others :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below solution :

```
$customerId = 7; //customer's id you want to load
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerId);

//Get gender value like 1,2,3
$genderValue = $customer->getCustomAttributeText('gender')->getValue();

//Get gender text like male, female
$genderText = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute('gender')->getSource()->getOptionText($customer->getData('gender'));

echo $genderText;
```

Comment: Dependency Injection is more recommended than object manager way

Comment: @RintoGeorge, Yes definitely we should use DI instead of object manager.